# Jquery when keypress in input need autocomplete English letter on number

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, replace

I would like to replace letters into numbers as they're typed inside an `<input type="text">` box.

Currently I use this code:

```
function Auto(str) 
{
  var search = new Array(
    "q","w","e","r","t","y","u","i","o","p"
  );
  var replace = new Array(
    "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"
  );
  return str.replace(search, replace);
}
```

// me need make find in find_str but i dont know how...

```
$("#find").on('keypress',function(){
  find_str = $("#find").val();
  alert (Auto(find_str));
});
```

Tell me please how make find letter in find_str and how to write this code?

P.S.: alert() only for test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replace` doesn't do arrays. There are a couple of alternatives, like multiple replacements, but transliteration seems good:

```
var map = {q: '1', w: '2', e: '3', r: '4', t: '5', y: '6', u: '7', i: '8', o: '9', p: '0'};
var r = '';

for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    r += map[str.charAt(i)] || str.charAt(i);
}

return r;
```

Also note that you're probably going to run into some focus problems, which are really annoying for users, so avoid things like this if at all possible.

Comment: I guess the `alert` is only for debuggin purposes. But yes, the focus change *is* annoying :-)

Comment: @Bergi: Yeah, I was assuming the result is going to be `val()`ed back in. Not everyone is always typing at the end of the box!

Comment: Thank you. Tell me please - can i use two arrays instead of one how in my example?

Comment: @LeoLoki: Do you get them from somewhere else, or can it just be a matter of a little rewriting? An object is overall a better way to hold a mapping...

Comment: @minitech I wanted to learn it for the future. That not to ask it again.

Answer (score 0):

[`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) takes a regular expression (or a string that will be converted to a regex) as the first argument and a string to replace matches or a function to compute replacements.

Therefore, you'd use this:

```
var map = {q:'1', w:'2', e:'3', r:'4', t:'5', y:'6', u:'7', i:'8', o:'9', p:'0'};
var keys = "[";
for (var key in map)
    keys += key.replace(/[\]-]/, "\\$&");
keys += "]";
var regex = new RegExp(keys, "g") // /[qwertyuiop]/g

function auto(str) {
    return str.replace(regex, function(match) {
         return map[match]; // the respective number
    });
}
$("#find").on('keyup', function(){
    alert( auto( this.value ));
});
```

---

If you really need to use arrays, of course you can do that, too.

```
var search =  ["q","w","e","r","t","y","u","i","o","p"],
    replace = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"];
var map = {};
for (var i=0; i<search.length && i<replace.length; i++)
    map[ search[i] ] = replace[i];
var regex = new RegExp("["+search.join("").replace(/[\]-]/g, "\\$&")+"]", "g");
```

Comment: Minorish thing: if the first argument is a string, it won't be converted to a regex. `'test.'.replace('.', 'orange')`

Comment: Thank you. Tell me please - can i use two arrays instead of one how in my example?

Comment: @Bergi tell me please how use this code for symbols value
 "[": '2' and  "]": '3' ?

Comment: @leo: Why would you want two arrays? A map (object) is much easier to maintain.

Comment: @Leo: The `]` would need to be escaped as `\]` inside the regex character class.